# BxSlider disable autoplay on certain width

Tags: javascript, bxslider

Not sure if I'm blind or there isnt one. I want to stop bxSlider autoplay on certain width? Simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you initiate bxSlider like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Before initiation, you could check the width first using `window.innerWidth`, e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (window.innerWidth >320) {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }
});
```

If you need to do this as well after initial loading of the page (i.e. rotating device) then you can destroy the slider like so:

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
slider.destroySlider();
```

If you need to do this after initial load, you'll need some way of detecting when to destroy the slider. jQuery has a method to check for this (`orientationchange`) which you can read here: https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/